# Click a thumbnail, display loading gif, image loads, gif disappears

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery and I'm trying to code a page in jQuery that allows the user to see a loading spinner while the larger version of the thumbnail they just clicked loads above, and then have it disappear after the image is done loading.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [ColorBox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) for that.  Alternatively, [this example](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/image-loading/) pretty much does exactly what you want.